# How to make user's input automatically go lowercase

Tags: java

I using Graham Mitchell's book Learn Java the Hard Way and one of the Study drills asks to make the code function so that if the human inputs a wrong capitalization it will still run with the program. In my case the input has to be lowercase.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DictionaryOrder
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;

        System.out.print( "Give me the name of made-up programming language:" );
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        if ( name.compareTo("c++") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE c++" );
        if ( name.compareTo("c++") == 0 )
            System.out.println( "c++ isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo("c++") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER c++" );

        if ( name.compareTo("go") <  0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE go" );
        if ( name.compareTo("go") == 0 )
            System.out.println( "go isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo("go") >  0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER go" );

        if ( name.compareTo( "java") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE java" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "java") ==0 )
            System.out.println( "java isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "java") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER lisp" );

        if ( name.compareTo( "lisp") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE lisp" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "lisp") ==0 )
            System.out.println( "lisp isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "lisp") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER lisp" );

        if ( name.compareTo( "python") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE python" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "python") ==0 )
            System.out.println( "python isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "python") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER python" );

        if ( name.compareTo( "ruby") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE ruby" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "ruby") ==0 )
            System.out.println( "ruby isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "ruby") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER ruby" );

        if ( name.compareTo( "visualbasic") < 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes BEFORE visualbasic" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "visualbasic") ==0 )
            System.out.println( "visualbasic isn't a made-up language!" );
        if ( name.compareTo( "visualbasic") > 0 )
            System.out.println( name + " comes AFTER visualbasic" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name.toLowerCase().compareTo("c++")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 
`name = name.toLowerCase();` 
after
`name = keyboard.nextLine();`

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Y03cB6)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple Java method of String class:

```
 String str="PEAR";
 str=str.toLowerCase();
```

And you will get:

```
"pear"
```